# I want to edit the python code for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program prints a pyramid pattern. I want to edit this code to get user input for any character not only * .

```
  def triangle(n):

        k = 2*n-2
        for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(0, k):
                print(end = ' ')

            k = k-1

            for t in range(0, i+1):
                print('*', end = " ")
            print("\r")



    def main():

        n = int(input("Input a number: "))
        triangle(n)



    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def triangle(n, choice):

    k = 2*n-2
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end = ' ')

        k = k-1

        for t in range(0, i+1):
            print(choice, end = " ")
        print("\r")



def main():

    n = int(input("Input a number: "))
    choice = input("Enter a character to draw: ")
    triangle(n, choice)



main()
```

Comment: you technically don't have to define the main function you could just run the code within. not sure if OP knew that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable for the printed character, called my_char perhaps, use the raw_input() function to grab it from the user via the keyboard, and then pass that variable as an argument to your function triangle(). This could look like:

```
def triangle(n, my_char):

    k = 2*n-2
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end = ' ')

        k = k-1

        for t in range(0, i+1):
            print(my_char, end = " ")
        print("\r")


def main():
    n = int(input("Input a number: "))
    my_char = raw_input("Input a character: ")
    triangle(n, my_char[0])


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(raw_input('Enter number of lines '))
character = raw_input('Enter char to print: ')
for i in range(1,n+1):
   print ((n-i)*' '+i*(character +' '))
```

you may add error checking so that user inputs only positive numbers